# How to create a custom partial class with T4 template?

Tags: c#, t4

I want a template which somehow accepts a `class_name` property and creates a class, name of which is the value of `class_name`

Ideally, I should be able to execute my template inside `MyClass.cs` containing definition for `public partial class MyClass`, and that would set `class_name` to `MyClass`

This template

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

public partial class <#=class_name #>
{

}
```

produces an error:

```
Error   1   Compiling transformation: The name 'class_name' does not exist in the current context
```

How do I put a definition of a `class_name` into it?

Comment: are you wanting to execute this template from your code (MyClass.cs) or visual studio as a .tt file in your project?

Comment: I want to execute it from visual studio

Comment: there is a similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946802/how-do-i-pass-a-string-parameter-to-a-t4-template) already, is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes. Didn't notice it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can define class_name as like this:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<# var class_name = "MyClass"; #>

public partial class <#=class_name #>
{

}
```

Comment: this is not really passing a parameter, it's just setting a local variable in the context of this template